# @OneToMany return null after insert

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-8

I have a problem

in a Java Web project using Hibernate
I have an entity that has an @OneToMany relationship

The @OneToMany relationship works correctly when I deploy the site

After saving, everything is saved correctly in the database but the @OneToMany of this new record returns null

If I do the deploy again then @OneToMany works

My Pedido class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "pedido.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Pedido p")
})
public class Pedido implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "valor_total")
    private Double valorTotal;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
    private Usuario usuario;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pedido")
    private List<ProdutoPedido> produtoPedidos;
    
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getValorTotal()
    {
        return valorTotal;
    }

    public void setValorTotal(Double valorTotal)
    {
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario()
    {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario)
    {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public List<ProdutoPedido> getProdutoPedidos()
    {
        return produtoPedidos;
    }

    public void setProdutoPedidos(List<ProdutoPedido> produtoPedidos)
    {
        this.produtoPedidos = produtoPedidos;
    }
    
}
```

My ProdutoPedido class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "produto_pedido")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "produto_pedido.findAll", query = "SELECT pp FROM ProdutoPedido pp")
})
public class ProdutoPedido implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "produto_id")
    private Produto produto;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pedido_id")
    private Pedido pedido;
    
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Produto getProduto()
    {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(Produto produto)
    {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public Pedido getPedido()
    {
        return pedido;
    }

    public void setPedido(Pedido pedido)
    {
        this.pedido = pedido;
    }
}
```

My PedidoB class

```
@Named(value = "pedidoB")
@RequestScoped
public class PedidoB
{

    @Inject
    private PedidoDAO pedidoDAO;

    public PedidoB()
    {
    }
    
    public List<Pedido> getTodosPedidos()
    {
        return pedidoDAO.getAllResults("pedido.findAll");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how do you save your entities, but my guess would be that you need to tell hibernate what operations should be cascaded to the child entities when you save the pedido.

What you're describing could be fixed by specifying these

`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pedido", cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE })`

[A brief tutorial on the subject](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types)

Answer (score 0):

In your case the 1:n relation has not been saved  by the entity manager, You need to define the cascade of action for the crud access of the entity. By this information the entity manager recognizes, that the linked relation must be process too for the provided cascading types.

In example if you define a REMOVE as cascade type and you delete a Pedido entity, all attached ProdutoPedido will be removed as well. Following an working example. You should apply the required cascade type to the cascade attribute for the correct cascading action of the entity manager.

All Infos here: [Jboss Hibernate Docs about cascade types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "pedido.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Pedido p")
})
public class Pedido implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "valor_total")
    private Double valorTotal;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
    private Usuario usuario;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pedido", cascade = { ALL })
    private List<ProdutoPedido> produtoPedidos;
    
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getValorTotal()
    {
        return valorTotal;
    }

    public void setValorTotal(Double valorTotal)
    {
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario()
    {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario)
    {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public List<ProdutoPedido> getProdutoPedidos()
    {
        return produtoPedidos;
    }

    public void setProdutoPedidos(List<ProdutoPedido> produtoPedidos)
    {
        this.produtoPedidos = produtoPedidos;
    }
    
}
```